# "on the campus" versus "at the campus"

Tags: prepositions

This question is based on this [one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/166753/difference-between-on-campus-and-at-campus) from English Learners, please read before marking this as duplicated or moving it.

Let me quote my fellow learner @Belle

> I want to know the difference between "on campus" and "at campus".
>
> I'm not sure when to put preposition 'on' and 'at' before 'campus'.

Trying to answer her question, I've found these grammar rules in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/at-on-and-in-place)

> We use **at**:
>
> with school/college/university

Being the **campus**

> the buildings of a college or university and the land that surrounds
> them

why is "on the campus" the commonest? [See [N-Gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20the%20campus%2C%20at%20campus%2C%20on%20the%20campus%2C%20on%20campus%2C%20on%20a%20campus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20campus%3B%2Cc0) by @Malik V]

Is "campus" a known exception to these rules? Is totally wrong to use "at"?

Comment: The campus are the grounds belonging to a college or university. It is not the school or college or university itself. I would compare it to "On site"

Comment: 'Campus' comes from the Latin for 'field'. Whether or not people know this, we usually say 'on campus' meaning 'on the area of land where the university buildings are'. I wouldn't say it's 'totally wrong' to use 'at', but it sounds less natural.

Comment: @KateBunting I already knew the origin of the word. I'm Spanish, we are Latin. We have "campo" (=field) ;-P I agree with you that it may sound natural but I was looking for some rule that backs up its use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*At the campus* envisions a university campus as a single point, like an arrow on a Google map showing a destination. *On the campus* locates something on a two-dimensional space which contains buildings and other facilities and can be peopled by student, faculty, or squirrels. *On campus* and *off campus*, without the definite article, refer to things or activities inside or outside the limits of that space.

> Because he had never ventured out this way before, having generally confined himself to the city proper, he arrived [*at the campus*](https://books.google.de/books?id=BOWe6oV2tOAC&pg=PA345&dq=%22at+the+campus%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii1YHpwo_bAhXBkSwKHVy5BJE4MhDoAQhUMAg) three hours before the game was scheduled to start ...
>
> We had travelled by train and turned up [*at the campus*](https://books.google.de/books?id=v0ml6qZBTPUC&pg=PT73&dq=%22at+the+campus%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-xKbWw4_bAhXEFywKHc6VDIE4PBDoAQgzMAM) to meet Professor Andrew and other staff members.

What’s topical in these two sentences is travel and arrival at a destination, not the campus as area/environment. In the following sentence, however, a new professor arrives:

> Before he arrived [*on the campus*](https://books.google.de/books?id=oaeDBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA93&dq=%22arrived+on+the+campus%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6zqOL1Y_bAhWJkSwKHVOyAxY4FBDoAQgtMAI) of Northwestern University in 1939, G. Donald Hudson had collected several years of experience in applied geography, teaching, and educational administration.

Since Dr. Hudson will be teaching at Northwestern and spending a great deal of time there, campus as environment is topical and his travel there is not. One can sense the same distinction in these two examples:

> Although some people [*on the campus*](https://books.google.de/books?id=AW6MAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA205&dq=%22on+the+campus%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4hYHayY_bAhWjF5oKHfsODSU4HhDoAQhEMAc) said the professor had been joking, the student clearly felt he faced a hostile environment.
>
> Some people [*at the campus*](https://senate.universityofcalifornia.edu/_files/committees/ucep/ucep.4.7.2014.minutes.pdf) wanted to initiate professional degree supplemental tuition for this program.

People *on campus* suggests the writer had interviewed them on the spot, and *environment* guarantees thinking of the campus as a public space in which people are expressing an opinion. In the second example, only the opinion is topical, expressed by faculty or administrators from the university.

A university with more than one campus will distinguish them as single-point locations, with an implicit or explicit contrast with other points, like these two Texas universities:

> Third- and fourth-year medical students currently train [*at the El Paso campus*](https://books.google.de/books?id=0H-r4oFs4YIC&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq=%22at+the+El+Paso+campus%22&source=bl&ots=e6p8MwZaFz&sig=xcw91SOoePGqnCav30tYwUo-FbM&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8i_jYv4_bAhVHOhQKHWerCZ8Q6AEwCnoECAMQAQ), along with residents in eight accredited programs.
>
> There was a specific decision that all members of the original student affairs staff should have experience working *on the main campus* for many years prior to their assuming a role [*at the campus*](https://books.google.de/books?id=2pHdXNN1lgoC&pg=PT52&dq=%22at+the+campus%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp3sm4xI_bAhWkKJoKHde_Bv04RhDoAQgjMAA) in Qatar.

The main campus of Texas Tech is in Lubbock, but medical students can also train at a different location, regarded as as single point. In the second example, employees work *on the main campus* of Texas A&M in College Station for many years like Dr. Hudson, but then assume a role  *at the campus* in the Persian Gulf state of Qatar.

As this last example suggests, a person can work on or at the campus, so, for instance, in these two examples from the same article about a research center in North Carolina:

> Dayvault, 27, works [*at the campus*](https://transforming-science.com/pillowtex-10-years-later-n-c-research-campus-behind-schedule-but-picking-up-steam-3/). From the balcony outside his second-story office at the UNC Nutrition Research Institute, Dayvault can look out over his ancestors’ land, which went from cornfield to Town Lake to Core Lab.
>
> About 600 people now work [*on the campus*](https://transforming-science.com/pillowtex-10-years-later-n-c-research-campus-behind-schedule-but-picking-up-steam-3/), including the employees at the new Cabarrus Health Alliance across Dale Earnhardt Boulevard.

Were the two prepositions reversed, there would be no change in meaning, only in the way *campus* is envisioned: point or space. The same is the case when talking about these two museums:

> These archaeological discoveries were deposited in 'the Eretz Israel Museum' [*at the campus*](https://www.euppublishing.com/doi/full/10.3366/hlps.2016.0140) of Tel Aviv University, a historical and archaeological museum in the Ramat Aviv neighbourhood of Tel Aviv.
>
> We went to the Arizona State Museum [*on the campus*](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g60950-d281585-r571097076-University_of_Arizona-Tucson_Arizona.html) of the University of Arizona, Tucson. The museum was focused on Native American history, pottery and baskets.

*On campus* and *off campus* parse as compound adjectives or adverbs rather than prepositional phrases: *a dry cleaner just off campus, off-campus housing, an on-campus fast food franchise*. Here,  the boundaries of campus as space are important, not the space itself:

> When a student works [*on campus*](https://www.edvisors.com/student-employment/jobs/on-vs-off-campus-jobs/), there are only so many job opportunities.
>
> Other factors include the schools services to help students move [*off campus*](https://books.google.de/books?id=e_JoT_2Mh9oC&pg=PT58&dq=%22off+campus%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipp-3_zI_bAhUkSJoKHUi_CJE4HhDoAQgoMAE) and how easy it is to secure housing.